# Store multiline output of `ls -1` in a variable

Tags: bash

I'm trying to cache list of files in a variable:

```
files=`ls -1 | head -2`
echo $files
```

So that if there's only one file -- use it:

```
files=`ls -1 | head -2`
numberOfFiles=`echo $files | wc -l`

if [ $numberOfFiles == 1 ]; then
  echo "Using $files"
else
  echo "ERROR: Too many files:\n$files\nI don't know which one to take."
fi
```

But much to my surprise `echo $files` does not preserve new lines of `ls -1` output. So `$numberOfFiles` is always 1.

How do I store multiline output of `ls -1` in a variable?

Comment: It works fine with `zsh` but there is an issue with `bash` prompt, since `ls -1` prints directories in 1 line when we do files=`ls -1` but prints in a new line if we just execute `ls -1`.

Comment: edited: sorry, missunderstood.

Comment: The biggest problem is not quoting the variable reference (use `echo "$files"` instead of `echo $files`), but I'd also recommend against [parsing `ls` to get a list of files](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: @GordonDavisson. Thanks for the link.